# Using Javascript to hide and show options

Tags: javascript, html

In the drop down menu below I am trying to make it show other sections or display multiple when selected..

```
<label>Calls</label>
<select id = "callList">
    <option value = "1">one</option>
    <option value = "2">two</option>
    <option value = "3">three</option>
    <option value = "4">four</option>
</select>
<select id = "Split">
    <option value = "Quality1">Sam's</option>
    <option value = "Quality2">Walmart</option>
</select>
```

so if someone picks option 2 it will display option 1 and 2 but hide the rest.
I am trying to use the js posted below to get it to display correctly but it wont.

```
function check() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("callList");
    var current_value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

    if (current_value == "1") {
        document.getElementById("Split").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("Split").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: *"it will display option 1 and 2 but hide the rest.*" - So it's supposed to hide and show specific ***options*** based on the first dropdown? Your code doesn't show any attempt at doing this, it's just hiding the entire `<select>`. Also, where are you calling `check()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.

Just add `onchange="check()"` in select dropdown as below.

```
       <label>Calls</label>
         <select id = "callList" onchange="check()">
           <option value = "1">one</option>
           <option value = "2">two</option>
           <option value = "3">three</option>
           <option value = "4">four</option>
         </select>
         <select id = "Split">
         <option value = "Quality1">Sam's</option>
         <option value = "Quality2">Walmart</option>
         </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check() {
var dropdown = document.getElementById("callList");
var current_value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

if (current_value == "1") {
    document.getElementById("Split").style.display = "block";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("Split").style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked however when I first start it(load the page) I have the option for one but two are showing. Like so and now option one doesn't work for displaying one http://jsfiddle.net/2pna2/457/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an event to call your function.

Test something like this:

```
<label>Calls</label>
<select id = "callList" onchange="check()">
    <option value = "1">one</option>
    <option value = "2">two</option>
    <option value = "3">three</option>
    <option value = "4">four</option>
</select>
<select id = "Split">
    <option value = "Quality1">Sam's</option>
    <option value = "Quality2">Walmart</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate the event for the Dropdown.
In case of `select` HTML element you can use the `onchange` event handler to respond to the change in selection for the DropDown.

```js
function check() {
var dropdown = document.getElementById("callList");
var current_value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
if (current_value == "1") {
    document.getElementById("Split").style.display = "block";
   
}
else {
    document.getElementById("Split").style.display = "none";
    
}
}
```

```html
<label>Calls</label>
<select id = "callList" onchange="check()">
    <option value = "1">one</option>
    <option value = "2">two</option>
    <option value = "3">three</option>
    <option value = "4">four</option>
</select>
<select id = "Split">
    <option value = "Quality1">Sam's</option>
    <option value = "Quality2">Walmart</option>
</select>
```